# Call string attribute from asp.net in a <div> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

It might be a simple question but I am confused. I would like to call a particular string attribute in codebehind from a `<div>` in markup.

How am I able to do this?

Comment: You might want to reword your question. I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: question not clear...can u explain lil more about your problem..

Comment: What Colin said! What do you mean call a string attribute?

Comment: I have a public string in c# and I would like to make a reference to it from the asp.net

Comment: @IT_info : You want to display the public string inside your DIV right...?

Comment: asp.net is everything ..lol..its "Markup"

Comment: create a label to display the string ..you can use `<span>` too.

Comment: Basically I want to be able to call the div from javascript to get the value of the string. Something like; document.getElementById('div_id').value

Comment: @IT_info : You are trying to assign the public string to DIV and access the DIV Value by Javascript... right..?

Comment: Yes, is it possible? @Pandian

Comment: @IT_info : I have added my Code... Try that...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a public variable from your code behind into an attribute on your page like this:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-my-value="<%= MyValue %>">
```

Then access it using javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').attributes['data-my-value'].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your markup:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server" myattribute="hello world">...</div>
```

You can read it in code behind using such code:

```
string myAttrValue = div1.Attributes["myattribute"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below...It will work...

**HTML**

```
<div id="divID" runat="server"></div>
<asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" OnClientClick="sam();" Text="Get Div Value" />
```

**C#**

```
public String Test = "Hello World !";
```

In `Page Load` SET this Value to `DIV`

```
divID.InnerHtml = Test;
```

**Javascript :**

```
<script>
        function sam() {    
        alert(document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML);              
        }
</script>
```